# Navigation Drawer: styling submenu / title

Tags: android, xml, navigation-drawer, material-design, android-navigationview

I am trying to style my navigation drawer after the specs from [google](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html). But I am not able to get this red marked submenu:

[image: Src : [google](https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0Bzhp5Z4wHba3RkZGRGhaM3c5ZDg/patterns_navdrawer_metrics1.png)]

This is my  current menu structure. I got the divider by splitting it into some groups but I don't get the title for the submenu.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group
        android:id="@+id/first_group"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/alle_termine"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_assessment_24dp"
            android:title="Alle Termine" />
    </group>
    <group
        android:id="@+id/second_group"
        android:visible="false">

        <item
            android:title="GROUPS"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:checkable="false">
        </item>

    </group>
</menu>
```

Is there a solution in xml or could it be done programmatically ? Both would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

You need an xml that resembles this:

```
<group android:id="@+id/some_group_id">
    <item android:id="@+id/some_item_id"
        android:title="Subheader">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/item_id_1"
                android:icon="@drawable/mail"
                android:title="@string/all_mail" />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/item_id_2"
                android:icon="@drawable/trash"
                android:title="@string/trash" />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/item_id_3"
                android:icon="@drawable/spam"
                android:title="@string/spam" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</group>
```

Create a group and add an item to it. The title of the item is what determines the title of the sub header like you want. Then you can add a regular menu with items to the sub header item.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @kingdonnaz is working. But in my case i am editing the menu dynamically so my solution was to add the submenu in code :

```
SubMenu subMenu = menu.addSubMenu(R.id.second_group, 1, 0, "Submenutitel");

subMenu.add(R.id.second_group, s, 1, "GROUP1").setIcon(R.drawabel.ic_test);
```